# Postgres - AVG calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Please refer to the below query

```
SELECT  sum(sales) AS "Sales",
        sum(discount) AS "discount",
        year
 FROM Sales_tbl 
 WHERE Group by year
```

Now I want to also display a column for AVG(sales) that is the same value and based on the total of sales column

[image: Please refer to the below, I need to derive the 4th column]

Output

Please advise

Comment: Consider upgrading your database. PostgreSQL 9.5 reached EOL last February!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVG()` as a window function:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    SUM(sales) AS sales, SUM(discount) AS discount, year
  FROM tbl_sales
  GROUP BY year 
) 
SELECT *,AVG(sales) OVER w_total 
FROM t
WINDOW w_total AS (RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY year;
```

The frame `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is pretty much optional in this case, but it is considered a good practice to be as explicit as possible in window functions. So you're also able to write the query like this:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    SUM(sales) AS sales, SUM(discount) AS discount, year
  FROM tbl_sales
  GROUP BY year
) 
SELECT *,AVG(sales) OVER () 
FROM t
ORDER BY year;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=05920c1809be6911449969c41a7819a0)

Comment: Could you please elaborate with above discount year columns

Comment: @Gallop I don't understand your question. What mean by elaborate with the above discount? Your expected result indicates you need a total avg() on the column sales

Comment: Ok understood....this works but in my scenario I will also be deriving a column say Sales * discount as a new column. How would the above change in that case ? Thanks

Comment: @Gallop see my last edit with this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=dbb85bd4f43796d5ada768844f461dfa)

Comment: Thanks this helps but in my actual use case I am getting duplicate rows....against 12 rows seeing 200. I have a where clause and a group by clause too

Comment: @Gallop could you share a data sample and the exact expected results based on it? I can't see how you have duplicated entries after the CTE with a group by: `WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    SUM(sales) AS sales, SUM(discount) AS discount, year
  FROM tbl_sales
  GROUP BY year ORDER BY year
) 
SELECT *,AVG(sales) OVER () FROM t`

Comment: SELECT 
   avg(sales) OVER w_total AS "avg_sales",
        sum(discount) OVER year1 AS "discount",
        sum(sales) + sum(discount) OVER jahr AS "derived",
        year1
 FROM tbl_sales
 WHERE year1 >= (select (max(year1::int)-15)::text  from tbl_sales) AND year1 <= (select (max(year1::int)+4)::text  from tbl_sales)
 GROUP BY sales,discount,year1
 WINDOW w_total AS (),
    year1 AS (PARTITION BY year1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238829/discussion-between-gallop-and-jim-jones).